# Android custom voice dialer command

Tags: android, android-intent, voice-recognition

I am looking to implement a custom action based on the user voice dialing (like hitting a button on their Bluetooth headset, or a dial button on their car).  Is this possible?  I know it is trivial by calling an intent, but I don't know if I can seamlessly integrate with the voice dialer.